# What is the meaning of a complex vector?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I do not understand when a vector is described, say $(2+3i)x$ (where $x$ is the unit vector in the $x$ direction), as complex. Aren't $2$ and $3i$ already perpendicular to each other, how can they lie in the same direction $(x)$ then? Or am I wrong in assuming them to be as straight lines with a definite length?

Comment: in which vectorspace lives x?

Comment: This is exactly the question I have, we were discussing the propagation of electromagnetic waves in a rectangular waveguide and one of the terms of the electric field looked like 2+3i(or something along that line). I assumed it was a real vector space because waveguides and em waves are real!?

Comment: Apparently you are working in some complex vector space $V$. That means you can multiply every $x \in V$ (the so called vectors) with an arbitrary complex number. For general vector spaces there's no real illustration for that, so you shouldn't confuse $V$ with $K^n$ for some $n$ and $K$ the field of real or complex numbers. (if $V$ has finite dimension, you actually can identify them though - but they are not the same)

Comment: If $V$ would have been a real vector space the expression $(2+3i)x$ would be meaningless for $x \in V$.

Comment: I think you're suggesting that 2+3i is treated as a scalar on the whole?

Comment: Yes indeed, because it is a scalar. It's only a vector in case of V being or containg the complex numbers already, but I guess thats not the case here.

Comment: Hmm thanks a lot, it'll be a while for me to digest that